# Error: `name` must be a single string. Using Count() function

Tags: r, dplyr, count

I am trying to run this line of code from a Kaggle script:

```
df1 <- combined %>%
count(name = character, drilldown = character) %>% 
arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
head(9) %>% 
rename(y = n)
```

However, when I run this code, I receive this error message:

```
Error: `name` must be a single string.
```

"Combined" is a dataframe containing 2 variables (character and dialogue, both of which are "character" variables.

```
ep4 <- data.frame(character  = c("Luke", "Leia"),
                  dialogue = c("Hello", "world")
                  )
                  
ep5 <- data.frame (character  = c("Darth vader", "Sidious"),
                   dialogue = c("My", "name")
                   )

ep6 <- data.frame (character  = c("R2D2", "ObiWan"),
                   dialogue = c("is", "Essan")
                   )
combined <- bind_rows(ep4, ep5, ep6)

str(combined):
'data.frame':   6 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ character: chr  "Luke" "Leia" "Darth vader" "Sidious" ...
 $ dialogue : chr  "Hello" "world" "My" "name" ...
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I am using the `count()` function from the `dpylr` package, not `plyr`. There is an issue with the "name" argument from the count function. If I remove the "name" argument, the code runs, but the Pie Chart that is created later on (using `df1` as its data) does not contain the names of the characters per slice.

Here is the Kaggle script: https://www.kaggle.com/couyang/star-wars-interac-drilldown-sentiment-analysis/execution

Comment: Hey, can you what the combined data looks like?

Comment: Welcome to SO, EssanRago! Please don't make us guess what `combined` looks like, either use a public database, or please provide unambiguous, easily-used data, preferably made programmatically with `data.frame(.)` or paste the output from `dput(x)` (where `x` is a small representative sample of the data, enough to show the variability of it). Please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The following is probably what you want

```r
df1 <- combined %>%
count(drilldown = character) %>% 
arrange(desc(n)) %>% 
head(9) %>% 
rename(y = n)
```

The error you are getting is that it is expecting a character to be assigned to the `name` argument. If you were to do this, you would need to adjust your pipeline as follows:

```r
df1 <- combined %>%
count(drilldown = character, name = "counts") %>% 
arrange(desc(counts)) %>% 
head(9) %>% 
rename(y = counts)
```